# Swing: Custom JSpinner Model causes StackOverflowError

Tags: java, swing, model, stack-overflow, jspinner

I want to write myself an `AbstractSpinnerModel` for a `JSpinner` that displays values of my custom-made class `Time`. I've extended `JSpinner`, which looks like this:

#### TimeSpinner.java

```
import javax.swing.AbstractSpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;

public class TimeSpinner extends JSpinner {

    public TimeSpinner() {
        super();
        setModel(new TimeSpinnerModel());
        ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) getEditor()).getTextField().setEditable(true);
    }

    public class TimeSpinnerModel extends AbstractSpinnerModel {

        private Time t = new Time(0);

        @Override
        public Object getValue() {
            return t;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(Object o) {
            try {
                t = Time.parseTime(o.toString());
                fireStateChanged();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }

        @Override
        public Object getNextValue() {
            // next 10 seconds step
            return new Time(((t.getSeconds() + 10) / 10) * 10);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getPreviousValue() {
            if (t.getSeconds() > 0) {
                // previous 10 seconds step
                return new Time(((t.getSeconds() - 1) / 10) * 10);
            }
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get a StackOverflowError because there seems to be a loop of Listeners notifying each other. But in all code samples I looked through it was done exactly the way I did it, i.e. calling `fireStateChanged()` in `setValue`. **Why does this happen?**

My stack trace (up to the point where it starts repeating):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.SunHints$Value.hashCode(SunHints.java:163)
    at java.awt.font.FontRenderContext.hashCode(FontRenderContext.java:352)
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(FontDesignMetrics.java:217)
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:286)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1113)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1626)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainView.calculateLongestLine(PlainView.java:639)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainView.updateDamage(PlainView.java:574)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainView.removeUpdate(PlainView.java:464)
    at javax.swing.text.FieldView.removeUpdate(FieldView.java:307)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.removeUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1624)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler.removeUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1884)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireRemoveUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:259)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleRemove(AbstractDocument.java:622)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.remove(AbstractDocument.java:590)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:666)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(JTextComponent.java:1669)
    at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField$AbstractFormatter.install(JFormattedTextField.java:948)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter.install(DefaultFormatter.java:125)
    at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.setFormatter(JFormattedTextField.java:464)
    at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.setValue(JFormattedTextField.java:788)
    at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.setValue(JFormattedTextField.java:501)
    at javax.swing.JSpinner$DefaultEditor.stateChanged(JSpinner.java:717)
    at javax.swing.JSpinner.fireStateChanged(JSpinner.java:458)
    at javax.swing.JSpinner$ModelListener.stateChanged(JSpinner.java:386)
    at javax.swing.AbstractSpinnerModel.fireStateChanged(AbstractSpinnerModel.java:119)
    at TimeSpinner$TimeSpinnerModel.setValue(TimeSpinner.java:26)
    at javax.swing.JSpinner.setValue(JSpinner.java:354)
    at javax.swing.JSpinner$DefaultEditor.propertyChange(JSpinner.java:752)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8430)
    at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.setValue(JFormattedTextField.java:798)
    at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.setValue(JFormattedTextField.java:501)
    at javax.swing.JSpinner$DefaultEditor.stateChanged(JSpinner.java:717)
    at javax.swing.JSpinner.fireStateChanged(JSpinner.java:458)
```

#### EDIT:

Here is my `Time.java`:

```
public class Time {

    private int sec;

    public Time() {
        sec = 0;
    }

    public Time(int sec) {
        this.sec = sec;
    }

    public void add(int sec) {
        this.sec += sec;
    }

    public void add(Time other) {
        this.sec += other.sec;
    }

    public int getSeconds() {
        return this.sec;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (this.sec < 3600)
            return String.format("%d:%02d", sec/60, sec%60);
        return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", sec/3600, (sec%3600)/60, sec%60);
    }

    public static Time parseTime(String str) throws NumberFormatException {
        try {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
            return new Time(i);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}

        try {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(str.replace(',', '.'));
            return new Time((int)(d * 60.0));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}

        String[] strs = str.split(":");
        int l = strs.length;
        int h, m, s;
        if (l == 3) {
            h = Integer.parseInt(strs[0]);
            m = Integer.parseInt(strs[1]);
            s = Integer.parseInt(strs[2]);
        }
        else if (l == 2) {
            h = 0;
            m = Integer.parseInt(strs[0]);
            s = Integer.parseInt(strs[1]);
        } else {
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        }

        return new Time(3600 * h + 60 * m + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Added `Time.java` to my question.

Comment: I would add the methods `equals` and `hashCode` to `Time` class and generate state change event only if the value is really changed (if old time is equals to the new - then no change state).

Comment: Where is the `main`? I want to be able to run it and get the error.

Comment: The whole project is on GitHub: https://github.com/smuecke/rating-timer You have to manually reset `Time.java` and `TimeSpinner.java` in order to get the error again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your working code after some modification

**TimeSpinnerModel** Class

```
package com.test;

import javax.swing.AbstractSpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;

public class TimeSpinner extends JSpinner {

    public TimeSpinner() {
        super();
        setModel(new TimeSpinnerModel());
        ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) getEditor()).getTextField().setEditable(true);
    }

    public class TimeSpinnerModel extends AbstractSpinnerModel {

        private Time t = new Time(0);

        @Override
        public Object getValue() {
            return t;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(Object o) {
            try {
                t.set(Time.parseTime(o.toString()));
                fireStateChanged();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }

        @Override
        public Object getNextValue() {
            // next 10 seconds step
            return new Time(((t.getSeconds() + 10) / 10) * 10);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getPreviousValue() {
            if (t.getSeconds() > 0) {
                // previous 10 seconds step
                return new Time(((t.getSeconds() - 1) / 10) * 10);
            }
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

**Time** Class

```
public class Time {



    private int sec;

    public Time() {
        sec = 0;
    }

    public Time(int sec) {
        System.out.println(Com.cnt.getAndIncrement());
        this.sec = sec;
    }
    public void set(int sec){
        this.sec = sec;
    }
    public void add(int sec) {
        this.sec += sec;
    }

    public void add(Time other) {
        this.sec += other.sec;
    }

    public int getSeconds() {
        return this.sec;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (this.sec < 3600)
            return String.format("%d:%02d", sec / 60, sec % 60);
        return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", sec / 3600, (sec % 3600) / 60,
                sec % 60);
    }

    public static int parseTime(String str) throws NumberFormatException {

        try {
            String[] strs = str.split(":");
            if (strs.length == 1) {
                return Integer.parseInt(str);

            } else if (strs.length == 2) {
                return Integer.parseInt(strs[0]) * 60
                        + Integer.parseInt(strs[1]);
            } else {

                int h, m, s;

                h = Integer.parseInt(strs[0]);
                m = Integer.parseInt(strs[1]);
                s = Integer.parseInt(strs[2]);
                return 3600 * h + 60 * m + s;
            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

When you create new instance of `Time`, number of instance goes beyond limits and cause `StackOverflowError`.

**Other way**:

As mentioned by [sergiy-medvynskyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1989769/sergiy-medvynskyy), 
You can override [equals and hashCode](http://technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html) to Time class and generate state change event only if the value is really changed (if old time is equals to the new - then no change state).

**Example code:**

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + sec;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Time)) {
        return false;
    }
    Time other = (Time) obj;
    if (sec != other.sec) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `t.set(Time.parseTime(o.toString).getSeconds())` - but yes, it actually works, thanks. Can you explain to my why this works but my solution doesn't?

Comment: Aaah no, I just saw you modified `parseTime` as well, nevermind